# PHP getting <div> in between after row count divided by 4

Tags: php, mysql

I need to divided all data into 4 columns. i have used this method but its not coming column  property

```
   $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
   $stmt5 = $db->prepare($sql1);
   $stmt5->execute();

   $rowcount = $stmt5->rowCount();

   $pages = ceil($rowcount / 4);
   $tempcount = 1;

if ($stmt1->execute(array())) {
   while ($row = $stmt1->fetch()) {
   ?>

       <?php if ($tempcount == $pages) { ?>

         <div class="column">
         <div class="ui bulleted list">

      <?php } ?>

          <a href="" class="item">  </a>

     <?php
     if ($tempcount == $pages) {
      $pages = $pages + $pages; ?>

          </div>
          </div>

     <?php }
     $tempcount++;
      }
       } ?>
```

how i can get this  columns after getting  count of data i have and add those divs in between.

for an Example 20 data rows 20/4 = 5 after each 5 data,  i need  start and  end to be added

```
    <div class="column">
    <div class="ui bulleted list">

      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>

   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
    <div class="ui bulleted list">

      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>
      <a href="" class="item">  </a>

   </div>
   </div>
```

// And so on

result will be like this

thank you very much

Comment: `% operator` can help [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). In loop, use it to create your divider

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: i updated the question for better understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proper code with comments

```
$tempcount = 0;
$pages = ceil($rowcount / 4);
while ($row = $stmt1->fetch()) {

    // if result of % (Modulo) is zero - you need to start new column
    if ($tempcount % $pages == 0) {?>
    <div class="column">
         <div class="ui bulleted list">
<?php
    }?>
     <a href="" class="item">ITEM</a>
<?php

    // if result of % (Modulo) is (pages - 1) - you need to close previous column
    if ($tempcount % $pages == ($pages - 1)) {?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
    $tempcount++;
}

// check if you have to close previous column 
// because it was not closed in a while loop


if (0 < $rowcount) {
    if ($tempcount % $pages != 0) {?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: everything is working on that way thanx a lot to help me out but `$tempcount % $pages != 0` if there is no data im getting division by zero error

Comment: So add a check somewhere - `if (0 < $rowcount)`

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the modulo approach mentioned above will help in these situations, I often find that writing your loops from a different perspective can help in sorting out the situation, and making things more readable.

Rather than looping through every row, and then inserting the columns where you think they need to be. Instead loop every item, but in a controlled count, wrapped by the columns.

I've switched the code to using `echo` just due to personal preference, you can still use php-breakouts instead if preferred.

> Please note this is untested example code, just to illustrate the point:

```
<?php

$stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$stmt5 = $db->prepare($sql1);
$stmt5->execute();
$rowcount = $stmt5->rowCount();
$pages = ceil($rowcount / 4);

if ($rowcount) {

  $stmt1->execute(array());

  do {

    $group = '';
    $group .= '<div class="column">';
    $group .= '<div class="ui bulleted list">';

    for ( $i=0; $i<$pages; $i++ ) {
      $row = $stmt1->fetch(); if ( !$row ) { break; }
      // presumably something would be done with $row here
      $group .= '<a href="" class="item"></a>';
    }

    $group .= '</div>';
    $group .= '</div>';

    echo $group;

  } while ( $row );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`% modulo` will help you [PHP operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). While you fetch, use it to create your divider. If using `div` and if needed, I usually add a tiny div with `clear: both` to make sure it breaks the line after the 4/8/12... results.

```
$cell++; 
$jumpline = ($cell % 4) ? "" : "<div class=\"spacer\"></div><br />";
$endit = ($cell % 4) ? "" : "</div>";
```